# sort a List<Tuple> from highest to lowest

Tags: java

```
List<Tuple<String, int[], int>>
```

I want to sort the `List` by the `int` from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[java.util.Collections.sort(list, Comparator)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

You will need to write a `Comparator<Tuple<String, int[], int>>`

Comment: Can you start a new question (since the question is different) and show the code you have so far?  Really just the code with the error should do - if that isn't enough me (or whoever else answers) can ask for more code.