# sorting List<Class> by one of its variable

Tags: java

I have a Class1

```
public class Class1 {
    public Class(String s, int[] s1, int soc) {
       this.s = s;
       this.s1 = s1;
       this.soc = soc
    }
}
```

I have a `List` of `Class1` (`List<Class1>`). I want to sort this list by `soc`, to get the `Class1` with highest `soc` first

Comment: Do you have any stipulations? Does it need to be a recursive method or something of high-efficiency (e.g. quicksort)? Or are you looking for an easy/simple implementation. You could ultimately use a for() loop, however, it would be very difficult for the computer to do this if you have a list of, say, 100,000 items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort a List<Tuple> from highest to lowest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017728/sort-a-listtuple-from-highest-to-lowest)

Comment: Not a dup... if he asked it there he would have been changing his original question into a different one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a Comparator

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Class1>() {
  public int compare(Class1 c1, Class1 c2) {
    if (c1.soc > c2.soc) return -1;
    if (c1.soc < c2.soc) return 1;
    return 0;
  }});
```

(Note that the compare method returns -1 for "first argument comes first in the sorted list", 0 for "they're equally ordered" and 1 for the "first argument comes second in the sorted list", and the list is modified by the sort method)

Comment: Won't work if one Class1 object has soc = Integer.MIN_VALUE for instance.

Comment: Code fixed now.  Previous version (return c2.soc - c1.soc) had some cases where it wouldn't work, for example if c2.soc is 2,000,000,000 and c1.soc is -1,000,000,000. "Nearly All Binary Searches and Mergesorts are Broken" - http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: Thanks for the catch, aioobe and Julius!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example:

```
import java.util.*;

class Class1 {
    String s;
    int[] s1;
    int soc;

    public Class1(String s, int[] s1, int soc) {
       this.s = s;
       this.s1 = s1;
       this.soc = soc;
    }

    public String toString() { return String.format("s: %s   soc: %d", s, soc); }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Class1> list = new ArrayList<Class1>();
        list.add(new Class1("abcd", new int[] {1}, 3));
        list.add(new Class1("efgh", new int[] {2}, 5));
        list.add(new Class1("ijkl", new int[] {8}, 9));
        list.add(new Class1("mnop", new int[] {3}, 7));

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Class1>() {
            public int compare(Class1 o1, Class1 o2) {
                return o1.soc > o2.soc ? -1 : o1.soc == o2.soc ? 0 : 1;
            }
        });

        System.out.println(list.toString().replaceAll(",", "\n"));
    }
}
```

It prints the following:

```
[s: ijkl   soc: 9
 s: mnop   soc: 7
 s: efgh   soc: 5
 s: abcd   soc: 3]
```

Comment: Does `s`, `s1`, `soc`, really need to be default access instead of private?

Comment: If they're private, they would need to have accessor methods for the comparator to do its work (unless Class1 implemented Comparable, and you don't specify a Comparator)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that implements [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), create your custom sorting method and then pass an instance of that class into this function: [Collections.sort](http://bit.ly/czThrN)

Comment: Example: Add getters and setters and you can use `this.list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Class1::getSoc));`

Answer (score 0):

While Scott Stanchfield's answer is generally the easiest way to do this in Java currently, if you have other functional things you might want to do with properties of your class it can be useful to make use of [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Function](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html)s.

```
public class Class1 {
  ...
  public static final Function<Class1, Integer> GET_SOC =
      new Function<Class1, Integer>() {
        public Integer apply(Class1 input) {
          return input.soc;
        }
      };
  ...
}
```

Then you can use its [Ordering](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class to sort:

```
 List<Class1> list = ...;
 Collections.sort(list, Ordering.natural().reverse().onResultOf(Class1.GET_SOC));
```

This uses the reverse of the natural ordering based on the `soc` property of each `Class1` instance to give the ordering you want.