# Sorting a tuple based on one of the fields

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

My question is the same as the one below, but the answer is very vague and I do not understand how to go through with it.
[sort a List<Tuple> from highest to lowest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017728/sort-a-listtuple-from-highest-to-lowest)
If you could describe in better detail how to do this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please post the code you have, and what's not working/what you can't figure out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to run this example I made for you and think what is going on:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Tuple<R, S, T>
{

private R name;
private S data;
private T index;

public Tuple(R r, S s, T t)
{
    this.name = r;
    this.data = s;
    this.index = t;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Tuple<String, int[], Integer>> tuples = new ArrayList<Tuple<String, int[], Integer>>();
    // insert elements in no special order
    tuples.add(new Tuple<String, int[], Integer>("Joe", new int[] { 1 }, 2));
    tuples.add(new Tuple<String, int[], Integer>("May", new int[] { 1 }, 1));
    tuples.add(new Tuple<String, int[], Integer>("Phil", new int[] { 1 }, 3));

    Comparator<Tuple<String, int[], Integer>> comparator = new Comparator<Tuple<String, int[], Integer>>()
    {

        public int compare(Tuple<String, int[], Integer> tupleA,
                Tuple<String, int[], Integer> tupleB)
        {
            return tupleA.getIndex().compareTo(tupleB.getIndex());
        }

    };

    Collections.sort(tuples, comparator);

    for (Tuple<String, int[], Integer> tuple : tuples)
    {
        System.out.println(tuple.getName() + " -> " + tuple.getIndex());
    }

}

public R getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(R name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public S getData()
{
    return data;
}

public void setData(S data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

public T getIndex()
{
    return index;
}

public void setIndex(T index)
{
    this.index = index;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is nothing else than the answer given there. To sort a list, you need either have your list elements have a canonical ordering (i.e. implementing the Comparable interface), or have a Comparator which does the comparison for the sort algorithm. Then you can use `Collections.sort` to do the actual work.