# How can I sort a java.lang.Iterable that contains a Tuple4 on the first field of the tuple?

Tags: java, sorting, tuples, iterable

I need to sort an Iterable.
It contains a Tuple4<Long,Long,String,String> and need to have it sorted on the first field of the tuple in order to calculate the time differences between the values.

```
Long pHandlingTime=0L;
for (Tuple4<Long, Long, String, String> in: input){
    elapsed       = Long.parseLong(in.getField(1).toString()) - pHandlingTime;
    pHandlingTime = Long.parseLong(in.getField(1).toString())
}
```

Any suggestions?

Regards Hans

Comment: you may implement a Comparator (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and then sort your collection with it

Comment: assuming a getter like `getFirst` exists: `Comparator.comparing(Tuple4::getFirst)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690537/sorting-a-tuple-based-on-one-of-the-fields

Comment: Tuple4 has getField()

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a Collection of Tuple4, you can define your Tuple4Comparator implementing the Comparator interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). The trick is providing a compare method which will decide which of the two arguments come first.

```
public static class YourComparator implements Comparator<Tuple4<Long, Long, String, String>> {

    // Let's compare 2 Tuple4 objects
    public int compare(Tuple4<Long, Long, String, String> o1, Tuple4<Long, Long, String, String> o2)
    {
        // Perform comparison, returning a negative integer if o1 is lower than o2, 0 if they're equal or a positive number if it's greater
    }
}
```

Once you have a proper comparator you can sort your Collection via:

```
Collections.sort(yourCollection, new YourComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what your `Tuple4` is you can do something like this to sort on first field.

Assuming that a `getFirst` method exists on `Tuple4`:

```
final List<Tuple4<Long, Long, String, String>> collect = l.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Tuple4::getFirst)).toList();
```

Assuming that a `getByPos` method exists on `Tuple4`:

```
final List<Tuple4<Long, Long, String, String>> collect2 = l.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> t.getByPos(0))).toList();
```